# Magento2 How to get the category collection as tree structure under multiselect field programmatically.?

Tags: magento2, adminform, category-tree

I want show  category collection as tree structure for custom multiselect field at admin end as reference like below

[image]

Comment: do you want to add the category tree in store->config or a custom form ?

Comment: @Manashvi Birla,I want category tree in custom form

Comment: check this link. might be helpful . https://belvg.com/blog/a-category-chooser-in-magento-2-backend.html